# As ptr1 and ptr are pointing to the same address, why dereferencing ptr1 and setting its value to 20, doesn't reflecting in x?

Tags: pointers

As ptr1 and ptr are pointing to the same address, why dereferencing ptr1 and setting its
value to 20, doesn't reflect in x.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    const int *ptr = &x;
    int* ptr1=(int*)ptr;
    cout<<ptr<<endl<<ptr1<<endl;   
    *ptr1=20;
    cout<<x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `x` is a `const` int. Modify a `const` is undefined in C++.